# Propel/symfony: just trying to build and load

Tags: symfony1, propel

i have just created a new project and this models and the fixtures below:

```
 culture:
     id: ~
     code:           { type: CHAR, size: 6, default: 'it', required: true }
     text:           { type: VARCHAR, size: 50, default: 'italiano',
required: true }
     folder_prod:    { type: VARCHAR, size: 50, default: 'italian',
required: true }

   sediOK:
     id:                      ~
     culture_id:              { type: integer, required: true,
foreignTable: culture, foreignReference: id }
     nations_id:              { type: integer, required: true,
foreignTable: nations, foreignReference: id }
     paese_indirizzo:         { type: varchar(32), required: true }
     ufficio:                 { type: varchar(64), required: true}
     indirizzo:               { type: longvarchar, required: true }

culture:
   italiano:    {code: "it", text: "italiano", folder_prod: "italian" }
   frencese:    {code: "fr", text: "francese", folder_prod: "francoise" }
   inglese:     {code: "en", text: "inglese", folder_prod: "english" }

sediOK:
   sede_roma_1_italiano:  { culture_id: 1, nations_id: 105,
paese_indirizzo: Italia, ufficio: "Ufficio 1:", indirizzo:
"XXXXX" }
   sede_roma_1_francese:  { culture_id: 2, nations_id: 105,
paese_indirizzo: Italia, ufficio: "Rome Office 1:", indirizzo:
"XXXX" }
   sede_roma_1_spagnolo:  { culture_id: 4, nations_id: 105,
paese_indirizzo: Italia, ufficio: "Oficina 1", indirizzo:
"xxxx" }
```

When i do `propel:build-all-load` it says:

> The object "1" from class "Culture" is
>   not defined in your data file.

So it's not inserting the culture fixtures but i dont know why...If I
remove the sediOK model and fixtures, and then do `build-all-load` the
culture fixtures are inserted ok.

Any idea?

Javi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The references to `culture_id: 1`, `culture_id: 2` and `culture_id: 4` are not defined in the above fixtures - you need to set the `sediOK` fixtures to reference the cultures by their identifiers, not their IDs in the database.

So, for you examples, the 'internal' fixture IDs are italiano, frencese and inglese. Change your lines `culture_id: 1`, `culture_id: 2` and `culture_id: 4` to `culture_id: italiano`, `culture_id: frencese` and `culture_id: inglese` respectively.

[Read the book](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/16-Application-Management-Tools#chapter_16_sub_using_linked_tables) for more details on this syntax.